# 1v for non-inverting op-amp input

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I need to reduce 5v to 1v for use as a reference voltage in an op-amp.

What would be the best way to do this? The simplest solution to me is to use a voltage divider, although I understand others have reservations about this.

Alternatively, a voltage regulator of sorts, although a quick Google, Mouser, Digikey, Farnell search yielded very few results...

Ideally I'm looking for a basic, and easy to understand solution.

Comment: How accurate does your reference voltage need to be? A simple solution (in part count) would be a 1.024V reference, but you could do it far cheaper with two resistors and an opamp buffer depending on requirements.

Comment: It is to be used as a differential amplifier, with 1v on the inverting equal resulting in 0v, 2v in 10v, and 0v in -10v. So, I should imagine it needs to be quite accurate.

Comment: How accurate do you need? 20% of precision input +\- 0.x% of +\-1.00V +\- y% regardless of input used as a comparator?  x or y??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A voltage divider can work well if:

1. Absolute accuracy is not that critical
2. The 5V source supply is stable and accurate
3. The current load you put on the central point of the voltage divider is 100 times less than the current you put through the two resistors of the divider will allow for ~1% variation
4. You use decent 0.1% or 1% resistors in the voltage divider
5. And you place a capacitor across the lower resistor in the divider to filter some of the voltage changes that are caused by sudden changes in the load current.

A very simple way to get a very decent reference is to use what is called a "shunt regulator" or "voltage reference" IC. One of these would connect to GND and to a pullup resistor to the +5V supply. The top side of the reference would be your stable voltage. If you need 1V you could look at the Analog Devices ADR510ARTZ. You can shunt up to 10mA through this part.

This picture from the Analog Devices data sheet for the ADR510 shows the typical operational behavior of the shunt type regulator.

[image]

Keep in mind that the shunt regulator will adjust the amount of current that it sinks (I<sub>Q</sub>) in order to keep the voltage drop across itself equal to 1V. The size of the bias resistor (R<sub>BIAS</sub>) sets the nominal current through the resistor/shunt regulator assuming no load current (I<sub>L</sub>). Once that operating point is established if the load is such that it wants to sink current then that additional current will be supplied through the bias resistor. If the load wants to source current then that extra current gets sunk through the shunt regulator.

As with any linear regulator (shunt like this one or other series pass type regulators) power dissipation is always something to consider. So if the load current nominal value is say 100uA because it just feeds impedance loads it would not be necessary to have there being 10mA flowing through the shunt regulator all the time. On the other hand if the load current had a dynamic change of say +/-5mA during operation you would want carefully pick the bias resistor such that the current variation to the load keeps the shunt regulator within its operating range. For the ADR510 that operating range of shunt current is from 100uA up to 10mA.

Comment: The ADR510ARTZ looks like it might do the job. Can you explain the need for a pull-up resistor? Would the positive terminal be the 5v supply, and the negative be the 1v output?

Comment: The shunt regulator has to have current flowing through it to produce the reference voltage. You tie the negative terminal to GND. The positive terminal then goes to the pullup bias resistor to your 5V supply. So for a 1V reference device the pullup bias resistor will have a 4V drop across it. So if you wanted to bias the shunt regulator to 4mA then use 1K resistor as the pullup bias. If you are familiar with a zener diode and how they work then you can think of a shunt regulator as an almost perfect zener diode.

Comment: But if the positive terminal is always tied to 5v, then surely there is always current flowing?

Comment: The shunt regulator will stay very accurate as long as the shunt current through the device is larger than the current you extract from the node between the bias resistor and the positive side of the shunt regulator. Since the shunt regulator regulates the voltage across itself the load current variation is well accommodated for and not sensitive like it is with a resistor voltage divider.

Comment: The + side of the shunt regulator does not go directly to the supply. And yes, the bias pullup resistor and the shunt regulator will always have current flowing through them. Just make sure that this shunt current is greater than the current you try source or sink from the node between the resistor and + terminal.

Comment: BTW. No one says that the shunt regulator has to be hooked up just like I described. If you had a stable 5V supply and a 4V shunt regulator you could tie its + side to 5V and have a pulldown bias resistor to GND. The output in this case would come from the - terminal and the bias resistor would have 1V across it.

Comment: So really, the bias pullup is just used to keep the current within the acceptable range required by the regulator?

Comment: You should look at the schematic picture that I'll add to my answer. This should help you to understand the reference better.

Comment: Still quite confused. If the regulator controls the amount of current it intakes, then why the resistor? In which cases is the resistor useful?

Comment: The resistor supplies all the current. Without it the shunt regulator would not work.

Comment: Well, the 5v supplies the current. The resistor only lowers the current. I just don't understand why.

Comment: The resistor allows for compliance against which shunt regulator can regulate the current through itself in response to load current changes. Keep in mind that a shunt regulator does NOT operate like a linear series pass regulator operates.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, I think I gotcha. What resistor value would be needed for a 5v supply, using the shunt regulator you mentioned? Also what does IL mean?

Comment: Since you have 5V supply and that resistor will have 4V across it why not try a 1K resistor so the nominal shunt current is 4mA. The IL is whatever current is taken by whatever you connect the 1V node to. If it just goes to your opamp then it would be the input bias current of the opamp.

Answer (score 0):

Use a specialised voltage reference IC, like [this one](https://www.mouser.be/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices/ADR510ARTZ-REEL7?qs=WIvQP4zGaniqWHvI6aygmw%3D%3D).